# Python: Waiting for the enter key OR button press (Text Based Adventure with GUI)

Tags: python, input, tkinter

Hi I am making a text based adventure in python and am having trouble with taking the user input, the text the user reads is in one text box and the input goes in an entry box.
I don't know how to get it to wait for the user to press enter or for a button to be pressed on the actual GUI.

I have tried:

```
textin.bind('<Return>', get_input)
```

but that didn't work for some reason I couldn't work out.

I have also tried:

```
import msvcrt as m
  def wait():
       m.getch()
```

but that made the GUI not show up or I wasn't using it properly.

Another thing I have tired is:

```
import time
  time.sleep(5.0)
```

but that had the same problem of the GUI not showing up until after the countdown.

I cannot use

```
input()
```

as I am using a GUI and if I use that then the GUI won't show up until after or some other problem (I may be wrong, I'm still new to some of this)

I need to know how I can get it to take the text in the entry when the user presses enter OR a button on the GUI, and all that needs to be in a function so that the main game can wait for them to enter a command.

The code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_input():                  #the button I put in had problems
    player_command = textin.get() #if this function wasn't before it

root = tk.Tk()                  
frame = tk.Frame(root)          
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

textout = tk.Text(frame, width = 50, height = 23)   
scroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame)                        
textin = tk.Entry(frame, width = 50)
button = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Submit', command = get_input)

textout.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.W + tk.E)         
textin.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.W + tk.E)
button.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = tk.W + tk.E)
scroll.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.N + tk.S + tk.E)   
scroll.config(command = textout.yview)

def main_menu():
    textout.configure(state = 'normal') 
    textout.insert(tk.END, "Welcome to The Adventure\n")
    textout.insert(tk.END, "What would you like to do?\n")
    textout.insert(tk.END, "Continue\n")
    textout.insert(tk.END, "New Game\n")
    textout.insert(tk.END, "Help\n")
    textout.configure(state = 'disabled')
    while True:
        if player_command == 'continue':
            load_game()          #other function
        elif player_command == 'new game':
            character_creation() #other function
        elif player_command == 'help':
            help_info()          #other function
        else:
            textout.configure(state = 'normal')
            textout.insert(tk.END, "Unknown command, type 'help' for hints")
            textout.configure(state = 'disabled')

main_menu()
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is an example of taking user input from text box.
Note that in this example **Enter** key is used to get the string on `current line` and `submit` button is used to print the currently held data.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.laststat=0#just to check multiple <Enter key> press do not delete the data
        self.currString=""
        self.tempString=""
        self.text = tk.Text(root)
        self.text.bind('<Key>', self.stripLine)
        self.text.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.text.focus()
        self.button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Submit', command = self.printData)
        self.button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def stripLine(self, event):
        val=('{k!r}'.format(k = event.char))[1:-1]
        if val=='\\r' and self.laststat==0:
            self.currString=self.tempString
            self.tempString=""
            self.laststat=1
        elif val!='\\r':
            self.tempString+=val
            self.laststat=0


    def printData(self):
        print 'Current String is :'+self.currString
        #print 'temp String is :'+self.tempString

root = tk.Tk()
A = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Also note that you can add similar functions (similar to `stripLine`) to handle **backspace** and similar other key presses